# How to send an AT commands with Header and Data Bytes

Tags: can-bus, obd-ii, elm327

this is my first Ask :D and i really haven't find something around.
I've already developed an app that read a lot of informations from attached ELM327 via standard OBD Pid commands and some other via CanBus.
But i have to read from different Headers in very strictly times and i would avoid to send 2 commands have the info (actually this is causing many reading errors between each read). This happen because in time X i send the header setting (ex AT SH 7AA) and then relative Pid request (ex 010A) but right after (X+1) i have to send a request on another header (ex AT SH 7BB) and relative Pid (ex 020B).
So i would know if i could send a sort of
"AT 7AA-010A"
and not
AT SH 7AA
+
AT 010A
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Regards, Luca.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry then. I'll try to be more clear. 
I need to know if i could send a UNIQUE AT command with Header And Data instead of an AT for setting Header and another to send the data to the header.
Instead of: 
AT 7AA 
and
AT 010A
use something like:
AT 7AA 010A

Answer (score 0):

With ELM327 (and the behemoth of clones), it‘s not possible.
You will have to consecutively switch header and then send PIDs.
The STN-chipset based OBD2 adapters can do something like that, they have an enhanced command set. Then again, for your application it might be better to utilize a real CAN adapter as opposed to an OBD2 one, since the former has no limits whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. Your reply clarify me the things well. Probably now it's time for me to go with a real CAN adapter (also for reading speed frequency).
Thank you again